# Azure Container Instance does not connect to a VM by hostname

Tags: azure, docker, dns, azure-virtual-network, azure-container-instances

I have an azure container instance that knows a VM by IP, but not by hostname.
I can solve this by doing the echo ipVM hostnameVM > /etc/hosts.
But is there any way to set the VNET DNS Server? If so, how do I access DNS servers Default (Azure-provided)?

Comment: Do you mean a VM separate from the container instance? So outside of the default VNET associated with your container instance?

Comment: Vm separate but same VNET.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify the DNS server of a Virtual network

Go to your Container Instance and select the Resource Group link. 
[image]

Then once at the resource group level select the Virtual Network resource

Once there, under settings you will see DNS servers

[image]

This will give you access to the DNS servers and you can specify your own instead of using the default Azure ones.

Comment: this seems to work for a VM connected to the VNet but not a container